# Azure DevOps YAML Pipelines: Add Git Tag based condition

Tags: git, azure-devops, yaml

I have a Azure DevOps YAML pipeline which always runs if I push a commit to my git main branch. That's Ok so.

But now I want to use git tags and conditons to run specific jobs in this pipeline only if the commit contains a specific tag.

How can I get the git tags to use them in a condition?

Thank you in forward

Best regards Matthias

Comment: Do you mean that you want to run the whole pipeline if a specific tag is pushed on the repository, or run specific steps inside the pipeline if a tag is pushed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What do you mean about "**`if the commit contains a specific tag`**"?

1. If it means a git tag created from a commit:

- For example, I have the tags like as the format '**`release-xxx`**'.

  [image]
- To run particular job in the pipeline when a tag is created as the format '**`release-xxx`**', you can set the YAML pipeline like as below. You can use the variable **`Build.SourceBranch`** to get the branch/tag name which triggered the current pipeline run.

  ```yaml
  trigger:
    branches:
      include:
      - main
    tags:
      include:
      - 'release-*'

  pool:
    vmImage: windows-latest

  jobs:
  - job: A
    displayName: 'JobA'
    steps:
    . . .

  # JobB only runs when the pipeline is triggered by the tags like as the format 'release-xxx'.
  - job: B
    displayName: 'JobB'
    condition: contains(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/tags/release-')
    steps:
    . . .
  ```

2. If it means the specified keywords contained in the commit message:

- For example, a commit message contains the keyword like as '**`release-xxx`**'.

  [image]
- To run particular job in the pipeline when a commit message contains the keyword like as '**`release-xxx`**', you can set the YAML pipeline like as below. You can use the variable **`Build.SourceVersionMessage`** to get the commit message.

  ```yaml
  trigger:
    branches:
      include:
      - main

  pool:
    vmImage: windows-latest

  jobs:
  - job: A
    displayName: 'JobA'
    steps:
    . . .

  # JobB only runs when the commit message contains the keyword like as 'release-xxx'.
  - job: B
    displayName: 'JobB'
    condition: contains(variables['Build.SourceVersionMessage'], 'release-')
    steps:
    . . .
  ```

Comment: This is not the solution I expected, but it certainly solves my problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can check the below pipeline. It is triggered based on tag and also executes a specific task based on the tag.

```
trigger:
  tags:
    include:
    - release.*

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- script: echo Hello, world!
  displayName: 'Run a one-line script'

- script: |
    echo Add other tasks to build, test, and deploy your project.
    echo See https://aka.ms/yaml
  displayName: 'Run a multi-line script'

- script: echo this pipeline was triggered from the first pipeline
  displayName: 'Second pipeline'
  condition: eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/tags/release.v5')
```

*When running the pipeline with release.v4 the task second pipeline is skipped.*

[image]

*When running the pipeline with release.v5 the task second pipeline is executed.*

[image]